# Loops Wordpress sem repetir o post

Tags: php, wordpress

Pessoal gostaria de saber se alguém aqui pode me ajudar com um query post ou loop em wordpress.

Então... faço a inserção com wp_insert e nao sei por qual motivo que duplica as vezes (talvez no click duplo do mouse) ao enviar via formulario.

Minha questão e seguinte.... mesmo com post duplicado no wordpress gostaria  de nao exibir tenho meu modelo que vou postar abaixo gostaria de saber se alguém pode me ajudar modificar e exibir sem duplicar ?

Desde ja agradeço aos amigos !

```html
<?php
$args = array(
  'post_type' => 'arquivos',


  );
?>
<?php $the_query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()): while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();?>
 

 
<?php the_title ();?>
 
<?php endwhile; else:?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Não há como você evitar dinamicamente a aparição de posts duplicados. O ideal é que você trate do problema de estar inserindo duas vezes no banco de dados.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo vou tentar !

Answer (score 0):

Como disse o **Hegon Felipe**, o ideal é tratar o problema de duplicação mesmo.

Segue abaixo uma solução só para fins didáticos (ele remove do loop, os posts com o mesmo título):

Edit 1: Remove os posts com a `meta_key` **Nome** em branco.

```
<?php
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
    $arquivos = $wpdb->get_results( '
        SELECT *
        FROM '.$table_prefix.'posts
        LEFT JOIN
            '.$table_prefix.'postmeta
            ON '.$table_prefix.'postmeta.post_id = '.$table_prefix.'posts.ID
            AND '.$table_prefix.'postmeta.meta_key = "Nome"
        WHERE
            '.$table_prefix.'posts.post_type = "arquivos"
            AND '.$table_prefix.'posts.post_status = "publish"
            AND '.$table_prefix.'postmeta.meta_value != ""
        GROUP BY '.$table_prefix.'posts.post_title
    ' );
?>
<?php foreach ( $arquivos as $key => $value ): ?>
    <?php echo $value->post_title ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Amigao so mais uma pergunta seguinte como que ficaria com essa condicao exemplo ta 'key' = 'Nome',
                    'value' = array ( '' ),
                    'compare' = 'IN'

Comment: Alem de nao duplicar gostaria que comparasse o campo personalizado  key e os value

Comment: Alterei o código, ficaria mais ou menos daquele jeito ali em cima.